# Android Text to Speech (TTS) only playing last value in foor loop

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have some code which pulls some JSON from a website, and I want it to loop through the string values, and turn them to speech.

The problem is, all the strings are correctly printed, but the text to speech only plays the last value. How can I get it to play each individual value whilst looping through the array.

Here is what have i done with the code.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    TextToSpeech t1;
    final String BASE_URL = "x";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        t1=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                }
            }


        });



        final JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, BASE_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {

                    JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("x");
                    JSONArray children = data.getJSONArray("x");

                    for (int i = 0; i<children.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject json_data = children.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("x");
                        Log.v("test", "Err:" + json_data.getString("title"));

                        String a = json_data.getString("title");

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {


                            t1.speak(a,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,null);
                        } else {
                            t1.speak(a, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        }



                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.v("Test", "Err:" + error.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
    }


}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`QUEUE_FLUSH` will cause any previous speech to be interrupted by the new one. You can change that to `QUEUE_ADD` and everything will be spoken.

These are explained [in the TTS documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#QUEUE_ADD).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concatenate the string and play the text at the end of the for loop like this

```
String my_text = "";
for (int i = 0; i<children.length(); i++) 
{
    JSONObject json_data = children.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("x");
    Log.v("test", "Err:" + json_data.getString("title"));

    String a = json_data.getString("title");
    my_text ="    "+a;
 }

 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
 {
     t1.speak(my_text ,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,null);
 } else {
     t1.speak(my_text , TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also faced same issue. hope my answer will help someone.

I have used arraylist of data with few interval gap in kotlin. you can change the separator string as per your array of data.

```
private fun convertTextToSpeech() {
val speech = arrayList.joinToString(separator = "?")
val myHash = HashMap<String, String>()
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"done")
myHash[TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID] = "done"

val splitSpeech = speech.split("\\?".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()

for (i in splitSpeech.indices) {
    Log.i("responseString",splitSpeech[i])
    if (i == 0) { // Use for the first splited text to flush on audio stream
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            tts?.speak( splitSpeech[i].trim { it <= ' ' },TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, bundle, null);
        } else {
            tts?.speak( splitSpeech[i].trim { it <= ' ' }, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHash);
        }

    } else { // add the new test on previous then play the TTS
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            tts?.speak( splitSpeech[i].trim { it <= ' ' }, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, bundle, null);
        } else {
            tts?.speak( splitSpeech[i].trim { it <= ' ' }, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, myHash);
        }
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        tts?.playSilentUtterance(750, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null)
    } else {
        tts?.playSilence(750, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null)
    }
}
```

}